# Mysql Update does not works with variables

Tags: java, mysql

basically when i try to use update with variables in java it doesnt works
ex:

```
String update = "UPDATE Clientes "
                          + "SET Nombre ='"+nombre+"' , Apellido='"+apellido+"', Telefono ='"+telefono+"' ,Calle='"+calle+"',NumeroPuerta='"+numpuerta+"' , Localidad ='"+localidad+"' "
                          + "WHERE Cedula = '"+ci+"' ";
```

that is the one that doesnt work but if i try the same but without variables it works
ex:

```
String update = "UPDATE Clientes "
                  + "SET Nombre ='luciano', Apellido='smith', Telefono ='111111', Calle ='avenue', NumeroPuerta = '456', Localidad='maldonado' "
                  + "WHERE Cedula = '123123' ";
```

thank to every one responding

Comment: what do you mean when you say `is doesn't work` ?

Comment: It depends on the values you provide for the variables. For security consider using prepared statements. In this way your code is open to sql injections.

Comment: With JDBC, we should be using prepared statements with bind placeholders, not including variables to construct dynamic SQL text.  From the code posted we can't determine, but this is a pattern that often appears in code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection. The OWASP project is one place to start:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Primary_Defenses

Comment: Can you tell us what error you get? Is it something like your mysql syntax is not correct etc etc.?

Comment: If there's some reason we can't use prepared statements with bind placeholders, then values included in the SQL text need to be properly escaped. For debugging, consider inspecting the contents of the SQL string, as a rudimentary approach, using `System.out.prntln` ... then take the SQL text to another client to test.

Comment: Are you using PreparedStatement, please share the complete the code

Comment: im learning mysql, excuse for my ignorance but i dont know what a prepared statement is.

Comment: It's a specific way to execute a query, different languages have different support for it but in jdbc/java the full class name is `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. Instead of placing the values in the statement, you use placeholders and send the actual values to the sql server so it can sort them out for you.

All of that matters very little to the actual potential issue, which if I had to guess has to do with type clashing (e.g. wrapping `0` as `'0'`, making it a string). Try running the statement directly (with values) on command line or in an sql client and see if it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: never do what you try now: `SET Nombre ='" + nombre + "'`...

It is direct path to SQL Injection attack. 
Instead use prepared statement with parameters like `SET Nombre=?`.

Second: only to find what's wrong with your query just use debugger or print resulting `update` string and find how it is different from working/hardcoded version.

**Still you must switch to Prepared Statement with parameters for real code**

UPD: example to start with (it is pure JDBC)

assuming you already have an java.sql.Connection ready:

```
    String nombre = "John";
    String apellido = "Doe";
    String cedula = "12345";

    String updQuery = "UPDATE Clientes SET Nombre = ?, Apellido=? WHERE Cedula = ?";

    PreparedStatement updStmt = myConnection.prepareStatement(updQuery);

    updStmt.setString(1, nombre);
    updStmt.setString(2, apellido);
    updStmt.setString(3, cedula);

    updStmt.execute();
```

Two things in JDBC to remember (forever :-) ):

1. there is no way to define same parameter multiple times in the SQL query.
   Parameters are just `?` marks and indexes go in order how `?` appear from begin to the end of SQL query.
2. parameter indexes start with 1 not 0

Comment: ok, thank you very much for respondig, learning mysql and dont know exactly what prepare statements are but ill figure it out.

Comment: you are welcome - look at answer update about Prepared Statement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this kind of Sql generation will lead you to Sql injection. You should use `PreparedStatement` with question mark and pass variables which Java will take care about sql injection, check, sql generation